# How to Optimizing My Apps for Chromebooks

Tags: android, google-chrome

Google Chromebooks now support the Google Play Store and Android apps.How can I Optimize My android Apps for Chromebooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the AndroidManifest.xml and set touchscreen as not required if you want to reach customers on non-touchscreen Chromebooks.

Adjust the settings so that the `android.hardware.touchscreen` feature is not required, as shown in the following example.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          ... >
    <!-- Some Chromebooks don't support touch. Although not essential,
         it's a good idea to explicitly include this declaration. -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
                  required="false" />
</manifest>
```

More refer here:
[Optimizing Apps for Chromebooks](https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/index.html)